# Change the order of all boot entries in GRUB2, not just the first

Tags: windows, linux, boot, grub2

It's quite easy to change the default boot entry through `etc/default/grub`. However, this only allows for the first entry to be changed. I want to be able to move all the entries in any order I like. What is the best/easiest way to do this?

Comment: Which version of grub is it?

Comment: It's grub2. I know grub is much easier to do this with.

Comment: Yep. For this and many other reasons I've decided grub2 is too ugly to live. I use syslinux/extlinux most of the time now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the order of the menu is usually not a requirement,
If you *do* want to go there, you'd have to re-order the scripts in **[`/etc/grub.d/`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#/etc/grub.d/%20%28directory%29)**

> The placement of the menu items in the `grub.cfg` menu is determined by the order in which the files in this directory are run. Files with a leading numeral are executed first, beginning with the lowest number. `10_linux` is run before `20_memtest`, which would run before `40_custom`. If files with alphabetic names exist, they are run after the numerically-named files.

Once you do these changes, executing "`sudo update-grub`" will re-generate your menu.

A 'dirtier' way would be to directly 'play' with the '`menuentry`' items of **`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`** file.
This will give you full control on the order (re-ordering scripts will still force an order on entries generated within each script), but note that, these changes will be wiped off as soon as an `update-grub` happens again -- like, when your kernel updates. You will have to re-do the ordering in `grub.cfg` again after that.

IMHO, its not really worth messing with the menu at this 'dirtier' level.
You should find the script re-numbering sufficient for your purposes.